# How can I build a search system to find all references that require an android permission in my project?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, permissions

Permissions that creep in between android builds of our app is a recurring problem for us at the office.

We work with Unity and use C#. In our project we use various 3rd party packages that we purchased from the Unity Asset Store and these packages update frequently. Sometimes we'll see a new permission creep in and we'll have to pinpoint the last git push to see when it exactly started appearing.

Doing all this stuff and tracking and scanning our code whenever we have an uncalled permission appear is a bit of a downer and takes considerable time.

I was wondering, theoretically speaking, if it's possible to write a script or a piece of code that creeps through our project and libraries within to give us a list of references that require android permissions.

Any guidance about this question is appreciated. I'm not a coder by trade and my knowledge isn't too strong over this subject so I apologize in advance if this questions is out of place.

Comment: While this isn't exactly out of place here, why not try posting this question to Unity's own [question board](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/)? I think you'd be more likely to find an answer there.

Comment: Hey Sylverac, I use Unity Answers as well and sadly that place is not well populated. I also  thought this question could relate to non-unity situations as well so I placed it here.

Answer (score 0):

So this is alittle bit tricky, because in Android Studio 1.5.1 seems like this function disappeared from lint for some reasons I dont know. So use any Android studio below 1.5.1 and it will be OK.

**Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name -> "MissingPermissions".**